# Why does my autofill code display #N/A in a cell I did not reference for VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I asked a similar question to this yesterday and I have run into another issue. Here is my code (I have my worksheets declared):

```
Dim lrp As Long 'last row for pricing worksheet
Dim lrf As Long 'last row for forecasting worksheet

lrp = Pricing.Range("A3", Pricing.Range("A" & Rows.Count)).End(xlUp).Row
lrf = Forecast.Range("A6", Forecast.Range("A" & Rows.Count)).End(xlUp).Row

'Pricing Worksheet
Pricing.Range("B3:AR3").autofill Destination:=Pricing.Range("B3:AR" & lrp)

'Forecasting Worksheet
Forecast.Range("B6:HO6").autofill Destination:=Forecast.Range("B6:HO" & lrf)
```

If we take the pricing worksheet for example, the reason why I used ("B3:AR3") is because I have formulas in all those cells that I want copied down to the last row (lrp). This code does autofill all of it down but it also adds the formula into the cell above it. So now B2 for example has a formula in it that reads "#N/A" when it is supposed to be my header. How do I autofill the formula down from row 3 (from columns B to AR) all the way down to the last row without including it in the header.

Thanks for all your guys help. Still new to VBA.

Comment: So the formula fills down from `B3`, but then also puts something in `B2`?  Same with `B6`, does it put something in `B5`?

Comment: Have you tried not using autofill and just copying those cells/formulas and pasting over the range?

Comment: Can you tell us what you get for `lrp` and `lrf`? If they're less than 3 at all, your range will include row 2.

Comment: BruceWayne: That is my exact issue

Comment: Hao: what do you mean what do I get for lrp and lrf?

Comment: Cyril: I am not quite sure what you mean

Comment: What if I use .filldown instead of .autofill?

Comment: @GCC What values do they have right before the AutoFill calls? For example, if `lrp` turns out to be 2, your first AutoFill will evaluate the `Destination` from `Range("B3:AR" & lrp)` into `Range("B3:AR2")`, which will get changed into `Range("B2:AR3")`.

Comment: @HaoZhang I have about 1200 rows that I need to fill.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
lrp = Pricing.Range("A3", Pricing.Range("A" & Rows.Count)).End(xlUp).Row
lrf = Forecast.Range("A6", Forecast.Range("A" & Rows.Count)).End(xlUp).Row
```

to

```
lrp = Pricing.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lrf = Forecast.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: I am still getting the N/A's

Comment: But are you getting that in where the title should be?

Comment: I am getting that where the title should be

Comment: Do you have data in Column A?

Comment: I have data in A all the way until row 1200

Comment: And you started with the titles in place?  This should do it.  It does not cover the unwanted cells when I run it.

Comment: You are going to need to step through the code to and watch the variable getting filled to ensure the equal what you think they should.